# What are the commands to logout and shutdown with a session manager?

Tags: shutdown, session, lightdm

I decided to write my own DE using these instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494457) it worked and I can login however I didn't use a panel so I don't have a logout button or a session manager.

I've decided to write my own session manager (instead of using established ones) so I can quit the session and return to the lightdm login screen. I've been reading and get the basic idea of what a session manager is but I don't understand how to actually log out and shutdown.

So how does that option work with a custom session manager? If that's too broad, how—after starting a session with a python script—do I return control to lightdm after shutting down all of my desktop applications, file manager, etc?

And for shutdown how do I properly shutdown a graphical desktop.

Answer (score 3):

The display manager passes control to your desktop session by running a program.  All you have to do to return control is have your desktop session terminate by calling `exit`.

For example, on my Fedora system, the display manager runs `/etc/X11/xinit/Xsession`, which starts the desktop session manager.

For shutdown?  Terminate all the processes you started (and their descendants), then use your operating system's shutdown procedure, e.g. run `init 0`, `/sbin/shutdown`, or similar.

Comment: The X server just runs one program, then exits (or restarts, in modern times). If you're running a DM, it'll `exec(2)` a shell to run a script, which then becomes the session controller. Traditionally, the session script started clients in the background, then ran the WM in the foreground so *it* would become the session controller. This is done behind the scenes by modern desktop environments with their own session management.

Comment: On modern systems, shutdown involves [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus). This allows non-root users to trigger a shutdown.